Under what conditions does $\langle x,y\rangle= \{x^my^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$?
$x$, $y$ are generators for a group $G$.
Under what conditions does $\langle x,y\rangle= \{x^my^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$? Basically, it means when does it happen that whenever $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, there exists $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y^nx^m= x^iy^j$?
If $\langle x\rangle$ or $\langle y\rangle$ is a normal subgroup, then $\langle x,y\rangle=\{x^my^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Say, if $\langle x\rangle$ is a normal subgroup, since $y^nx^my^{-n} = x^i$ for some $i$, we have $y^nx^m=x^iy^n$. As a corollary, if $\langle x,y\rangle \neq \{x^my^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, then both $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle y\rangle$ are not normal.
So, I wonder under what conditions does $\langle x,y\rangle= \{x^my^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$? This condition should be weaker than $\langle x\rangle$ or $\langle y\rangle$ being normal.

Use \langle and \rangle, not < and >

why $ y^ix^jy^{-m } = x^n \implies  y^{i-m}x^p = x^n$ , If $\langle x\rangle$ or $\langle y\rangle$  is a normal subgroup, then the condition should be satisfied.

@Balajisb subgroups never have empty intersection. And you have no warrant for going from $y^ix^jy^{-m}=x^n$ to $y^{i-m}x^j=x^n$, as $x$ and $y$ are not assumed to commute. Your entire comment is incorrect. Though of course you can find powers that are equal: just take $y^0=x^0$.

Let $G = \langle x,y \rangle$.
Your question is: when $G = HK$ with $H = \langle x \rangle$ and $K = \langle y \rangle$? (Here for subsets $X$ and $Y$ of $G$, denote $XY = \{xy : x \in X, y \in Y\}$.
It is probably difficult to say too much in general. But in your setup, the following are equivalent (none of this relies on $H$ and $K$ being cyclic, just on $G = \langle H, K \rangle$.)

$G = HK$.
$HK = KH$.
$H$ acts transitively on the cosets of $K$.
$K$ acts transitively on the cosets of $H$.

It is true that $HK = KH$ if one of $H$ or $K$ is a normal subgroup, but examples show that this is not always true.

why 3) $\implies$ 1)?

@femto If 3) holds, then every coset of $K$ is on the same $H$-orbit as the coset $K$. In other words, for all $g \in G$, there exists $h \in H$ such that $h(gK) = K$. Then $hg \in K$, so $g \in HK$.
